# Using the result of a sql linq query leads to the database beeing queried twice

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I query a database and push the result out to the console and a file using two methods like this:

```
var result = from p in _db.Pages
             join r in rank on p.PkId equals r.Key
             orderby r.NumPages descending
             select new KeyNameCount
                                    {
                                        PageID = p.PkId,
                                        PageName = p.Name,
                                        Count = r.NumPages
                                    };

WriteFindingsToFile(result, parentId);
WriteFindingsToConsole(result, parentId);
```

IEnumerable<T>, not IQuerable<T> is used as parametertype for result when used as a parameter in the two method calls.

In both calls the result is iterated in a foreach. This leads to two identical calls against the database, one for each method.

I could refactor the two methods into one and only use one foreach, but that would fast become very hard to maintain (adding write to html, write to xml, etc.)

I am pretty sure this is a farly common question, but using google has not made me any wiser, so I turn to you guys :-)

Comment: Why don't you use a lambda expression and query the `result`? Can you be more specific on what you are looking for??

Comment: @SagarBhat, the two methods iterate over every item in `result`, so I saw no reason to use lamdba over foreach to do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every time you access a LINQ query it will requery the database to refresh the data. To stop this happening use `.ToArray()` or `.ToList().`

e.g.

```
var result = (from p in _db.Pages
             select p).ToList(); //will query now

Write(result);  //will not requery
Write(result2); //will not requery
```

It's important to understand that a raw LINQ query is run when it is used, not when it is written in the code (e.g. don't dispose of your _db before then).

It can be surprising when you realise how it *really* works. This allows method chaining and later modification of the query to be reflected in the final query run on the DB. It is important to always keep in mind as it can cause run-time bugs that will not be caught at compile time, usually because the DB connection is closed before the list is used, as you are passing around what appear to be a simple IEnumerable.

EDIT: Changed to remove my opinion and reflect the discussion in the comments. Personally I think the compiler should assume that the end result of chained queries is immediately run unless you explicitly say that it'll be further modified later. Just to avoid the run-time bugs it inevitably causes.

Comment: I do not agree with your 'MS Magic that is confusing' part. Deferred execution is a fundamental part of composing linq queries. How else would you add parts to a query (like an extra filter, or an orderby) and execute it when you are ready. By using deferred execution, Microsoft gives you the choice when to hit the database instead of executing it on query definition. It is a part that is often misunderstood but that's not Microsoft's fault.

Comment: @Wouter de Kort, sorry, I edited it just before you posted this. I remembered why they did it just after posting that. TBH they should have made you have to do something to defer this by default rather than enabling by default. It's an incredibly easy source of bugs and performance problems.

Comment: @mattmanser And what should be the default behavior? Always give a list? What if I want an array? Or Count, Any, First, Single, Max, Sum, Last, .....? :) I think it wouldn't be possible to 'execute the query immediately' because the user has to choose explicitly what should be done and which result should be returned.

Comment: That the query is first run when used is great in my book since a) that makes it posible to break the query up in smaller code blocks --> easier to read, b) parts of the query can be added/ommited easily based on business (or other) logic and c) that same logic can lead to not having to run the query after all.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the [function definition for IQuerayble](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351562.aspx), you will see that it also implements IEnumerable. So you can pass IQueryable as parameter to an IEnumerable function without actually enumerating it.

But because of Linqs deffered execution pattern, the IQueryable will only be executed against the database when you iterate over it (with a for loop for example as in your case, or with ToList() or functions like First/Single).

[Here is a blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx) that explains how this works.

If you change your code to the following you will hit the database only once and then pass the result in memory to your functions:

```
var result = (from p in _db.Pages
             join r in rank on p.PkId equals r.Key
             orderby r.NumPages descending
             select new KeyNameCount
                                    {
                                        PageID = p.PkId,
                                        PageName = p.Name,
                                        Count = r.NumPages
                                    }).ToList();

WriteFindingsToFile(result, parentId);
WriteFindingsToConsole(result, parentId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Any time you iterate over your LINQ result the databased will be queried too.

This is called **Deferred query execution**. You may have a deeper look into at one (out of many) corresponding [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738633.aspx) articles!

`Execution of the query is deferred until the query variable is iterated over in a foreach or For Each loop`