# How to create an Extension method for a list to return null if list is empty or return full list

Tags: c#

I have multiple lists of different objects. 
for all objects I want to return null if it's an empty list or return full list.
How can i achieve that?
I want to do something like

```
address = person.addresses.tolist().count > 0 ? person.addresses.tolist : null;
aliases = person.aliases.tolist().count > 0 ? person.aliases.toList() : null;
trackingCodes = person.trackingCodes .tolist().count > 0 ? person.trackingCodes .toList() : null;
```

In the above line of code, i am computing addresses list twice.

I was wondering if i could create an extension method that can be uses as
`address = patient.addresses.tolist().GetListOrNull()`
and the `GetListOrNull()` method returns either list or null value.
Is this possible?

Comment: I do not know how to create GetListOrNull() method.

Comment: I understand that now - the lack of formatting before threw me off :-)

Comment: Can I strongly suggest you **not** do this? It is _almost_ always better to return an empty list rather than a `null` one.

Comment: This feels like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . **Why** do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extension methods have to be in a static class and have to be static.

You could write something like:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IList<T> GetListOrNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        if (items == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        // optimization to avoid creating a new list when the input already implements `IList`
        if (!(items is IList<T> tmp))
        {
            tmp = items.ToList();
        }
        return tmp.Any() ? tmp : null;
    }

    // or a list-specific version
    public static IList<T> GetListOrNull<T>(this IList<T> items)
    {
        if (items == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return items.Any() ? items : null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a version that works on IEnumerable so that it can be a little more generic.
I think .Any() is a little more succinct than .Count > 0

```
public static class MyExtentions 
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> ToNullIfEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> container) 
    {
        if(container == null || !container.Any())
            return null;
        else
            return container;            
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you're taking `IEnumerable<T>` and not converting the data to a list first, that `.Any()` could result in a second database call.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  .Any() begins to iterate a collection, then returns true once it hits the first element. How does this cause a database call in any way?

Comment: Because `IEnumerable` doesn't always represent static data. For example, calling your method like so: `foreach (var value in mongoCollection.Find(x => x.Name == "test").ToEnumerable())` would result in two database calls. One for the any, and another to actually iterate. Note that returning `container.ToList()` within your method would just move that iteration. [Example question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8603811/using-the-result-of-a-sql-linq-query-leads-to-the-database-beeing-queried-twice) ** Note that I'm not saying it will iterate all items twice, just hit the db twice.

Comment: I've created an [example demonstrating the issue](https://rextester.com/NQBV43775) for you. Imagine the loop in the `GetTestData()` method as something like an `SqlDataReader` read loop, etc.

Comment: Thanks @John, the example is very helpful. I didn't look at the solution from anything other than a static collection. Mittal Soni  if someone has provided you with a good explanation and solution, you should mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: No worries. Know that I didn't downvote your answer - I've done the same thing myself before too :)